# Child page hides after opening from main page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis

In ASP.NET Web Application, there is a main window (Default.aspx or home page) and there is a child window(a new aspx page). When I open child page with javascript on a button click using window.open() method by specifying its url.
C# code on Button Click Event:

```
protected void BtnChildPage_Clicked(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(@"<script language='javascript'>");
        sb.Append(@"OpenChildPage('" + sQueryString + "')");
        sb.Append(@"</script>");

        //register startup script with button
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(BtnPartMemo, this.GetType(), sScriptName, sb.ToString(), false);
    }
```

Javascript code to opne Child Page:

```
var childmWindow;
function OpenChildPage(sQueryString) {

    var width = 655;
    var height = 508;
    var left = (screen.width - width) / 2;
    var top = (screen.height - height) / 2;
    var params = 'width=' + width + ', height=' + height;
    params += ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left;
    params += ', directories=no';
    params += ', location=no';
    params += ', menubar=no';
    params += ', resizable=yes';
    params += ', scrollbars=yes';
    params += ', status=yes';
    params += ', toolbar=no';
    childmWindow = window.open('DirectoryName/ChildPage.aspx' + '?ViewerId=' + sQueryString,
                                'Child Page' + sViewerId, params);
    childmWindow.focus();

}
```

The child window doesn't appear in front of main window. I tried window.focus() after calling window.open() method but it hides the child window after opening.

This behavior is only observed after deploying application in IIS 5.1 using Win XP.
While I execute it from code, it behaves accordingly, but after deploying in IIS, it hides the child window after opening.

How to overcome this behavior ?

Comment: Post your code,otherwise no one can judge the answer.

Comment: question is updated with code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you need to open child window in small window in front of your main page?
If this is correct, then this should help:

```
window.open('DirectoryName/ChildPage.aspx','_blank', params);
```

if `'_blank'` will work but you'll need "'Child Page' + sViewerId" for some reason then

```
window.open('DirectoryName/ChildPage.aspx','_blank'+'Child Page' + sViewerId, params);
```

_blank should be used firstly, otherwise it won't work (firstly wanted to comment it but I can't for some reason, so I hope it will help).